# How to merge iterator of streams?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a program that scrapes links from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlist/english/oxford3000/) using Rust. I'm using `hyper` and `futures`.

I have a collection of links to each section and use `stream::unfold` to construct access to each page:

```
// Returns the links scraped, and probably Uri to the next page.
fn process_body_and_return_next(body: Body) -> (Vec<String>, Option<Uri>) { ... }

// In main()
let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
let handle = core.handle();
let client = Client::new(&handle);
let uris = ...

let jobs = uris.map(|uri| {
    stream::unfold(Some(uri), |uri| {
        uri.map(|uri| {
            client
                .get(uri)
                .and_then(|res| res.body().concat2())
                .map(process_body_and_return_next)
        })
    })
});
```

Now I've got a `impl Iterator<Item = impl Stream<Item = Vec<String>>>`. How can I merge it to a single `Stream` of `Vec`s, like using `stream::futures_unordered` to merge `Future`s?

---

Edit: I tried combine `stream::iter_ok` and `stream::Stream::flatten`:

```
let flattened = ::futures::stream::iter_ok(jobs)
    .flatten();
```

But that's not efficient since I want to send several web request asynchronously. The combined `Stream` should produce value whenever a inner `Stream` is ready.

Answer (score 4):

An iterator may be turned into a stream using [`futures::stream::iter_ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/fn.iter_ok.html), this allows your iterator of streams to be turned into a stream of streams:

```
::futures::stream::iter_ok(jobs)
```

You can then flatten this stream of streams into a single stream of all items using [`Stream::flatten()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.flatten):

```
let flattened = ::futures::stream::iter_ok(jobs)
    .flatten();
```

Comment: But in that way the items will be evaluated one by one, rather than simultaneously. Is there a `Stream` version of `futures_unordered`?

Comment: @PengGuanwen your requirement is not clear.  You wanted a `Stream` of items that are produced by the inner streams.  How could anything be delivered "simultaneously"?

Comment: I need an unordered buffered `Stream`. When you combine an `Iterator` of `Future`s, you can use either `stream::futures_ordered` or `stream::futures_unordered`, and if you use the latter, the `Stream` will produce value whenever one of the `Future`s is available. When you have an `Stream` of `Future`s, you can use `stream::Stream::buffer_unordered` to achieve this. But in my case, a `Iterator` of `Stream`s is hard to combine that way. I can't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The [`select`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.select) combinator takes two `Stream`s and yields when one of the two streams is ready.

In order to select from more than two streams, you can chain calls to `select`. However, since you don't know in advance the number of streams you have to select on, you'll have to box the intermediate streams in order to erase the specific `Stream` type, so that the program type-checks.

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::Stream;

fn select_all<'a, I, T, E>(seq: I) -> Box<Stream<Item = T, Error = E> + 'a>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Stream<Item = T, Error = E> + 'a,
    T: 'a,
    E: 'a,
{
    let mut iter = seq.into_iter();
    let mut result = Box::new(iter.next().expect("got an empty list of streams"))
        as Box<Stream<Item = T, Error = E>>;
    while let Some(next) = iter.next() {
        result = Box::new(result.select(next));
    }

    result
}
```

There's certainly a more efficient way to implement this, though. There is a [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) combinator for futures, but there isn't one yet for streams. Perhaps you could implement it yourself and submit it as a pull request!

Comment: It seems that there is a [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2/futures/stream/fn.select_all.html) for streams in futures 0.2 (not stable version). It seems to be implemented without any use of `Box`.